# Why form_tag is generating form with wrong url (No route matches [POST] "/assets")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controllers

I looked at some posts about this question, but I can't get how to solve this.

I have index page on which I have form which I will use to take them from params hash from it.

Here is form:

```
  <%= form_tag(:action => '/show', :method => "get") do %>
   <%= datepicker_input "report","start_date", :dateFormat => "dd/mm/yy" %>
   <%= datepicker_input "report", "end_date", :dateFormat => "dd/mm/yy"%>
   <%=  submit_tag "Run Report", :class => "btn super", :id => "btn "%>
   < %end %>
```

and input's names:

```
  <input id="report_start_date" name="report[start_date]" size="30" type="text" class="hasDatepicker">
  <input id="report_end_date" name="report[end_date]" size="30" type="text" class="hasDatepicker">
```

but it is generating URL like this:

```
  action="/assets?action=%2Fshow&controller=financial_reports&method=get"
```

Also, I need to pass params values into index controller, like this :

```
def index
 start_date = params[:start_date]
 end_date = params[:end_date]
  @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports#.where(:created_at => the_start.to_date..the_end.to_date)
end
```

but it of course giving me error 'undefined method for nilClass'.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Just look at your log, and see what params your controller is actually receiving.  Might they be referenced as params[:report][:start_date], and params[:report][:end_date]?

Comment: Now it gives me `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I managed to do this, but now I have another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the space between < and & in your last line a typo in SO? Otherwise Ruby might mess things up because the form tag is ended at complete another place than you think it is...